# hapijs OnRequest server extension doesn't access the server plugin

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

i18n for internationalization purpose.

When user send the language code on url i will change the language of i18n like this http://localhost:8080/signup?language=en
For that i am using the server extension OnRequest. So that on it will global for each route,
but the problem occurs is when i access the i18n in OnRequest its shows undefined error
But in the route handler it shows all the properties of the hapi-i18n
Here is my code and output

```
server.ext('onRequest', function(request, response){
console.log("pre handler");
console.log(request.i18n);


return response.continue();
});
```

Output:
**Undefined**

But in the handler

```
{
    method : 'POST',
    path   : "/signup",
    config : {
        tags        : ['api'],
        description : 'Customer signup',
    },
    handler: function(request, response){
        console.log(request.i18n);
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
{ __: [Function],
    __n: [Function],
   getLocale: [Function],
   setLocale: [Function],
   getCatalog: [Function],
   locale: 'en' 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the onPostAuth extension point as the module you are using manipulates request object in the onPreAuth extension point during request object lifecycle.